# Dokan Vendor Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dokan

This unit of measurement field can be accessed from the wordpress admin dashboard. But I want to access it from the product section of the dokan vendor dashboard.How is this done?

I'm happy if anyone can provide code for this.